# java 8 nested loop with stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a for loop iterating over a `Integer [][]map`.
Currently is like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
        if(map[i][j] == 1)
            q.add(new Point(i,j));
    }
}
```

Instead of 2d array, suppose I have `List<List<Integer>> maps2d`.
How would I do that with streams?

So far I got this:

```
maps2d.stream()
      .forEach(maps1d -> maps1d.stream()
                               .filter(u -> u == 1)
                               .forEach(u -> {

                               }
      )
);
```

Is it correct so far?
If yes, how do I count `i` and `j` in order to create the `new Point(i,j)` and add it to `q` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to use streams for the same purpose then one option is to use nested `IntStream`s to iterate over the indices. As an example:

```java
public static List<Point> foo(List<List<Integer>> map) {
  return IntStream.range(0, map.size()) // IntStream
      .mapToObj(
          i ->
              IntStream.range(0, map.get(i).size())
                  .filter(j -> map.get(i).get(j) == 1)
                  .mapToObj(j -> new Point(i, j))) // Stream<Stream<Point>>
      .flatMap(Function.identity()) // Stream<Point>
      .collect(Collectors.toList()); // List<Point>
}
```

Personally, I don't find that tremendously readable. Note you can still use nested for loops with your list, similar to your current solution:

```java
public static List<Point> foo(List<List<Integer>> map) {
  List<Point> result = new ArrayList<>();
  for (int i = 0; i < map.size(); i++) {
    List<Integer> inner = map.get(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < inner.size(); j++) {
      if (inner.get(j) == 1) {
        result.add(new Point(i, j));
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that a normal for loop answer would be more readable while still answering the question. A normal for loop is far more readable and this is an example of the stream API being possible, but takes away from readability.

Comment: Yikes. I know the authors were operating under a crazy number of constraints when designing the stream library, but man this code is just nasty.

Comment: @Alexander The main problem here is streaming over a list while remembering the indices which the stream API does not appear to be designed for. I also prefer using the Google-style format, as I did above, which may be slightly foreign to people used to other styles.

Comment: My main gripe is that there needs to be a distinction between `Stream` and `IntStream`. In Java, people are always raving about how awesome objects are, how allocations are cheap and GC is "so fast now." Yet when it comes down to it, `IntStream` had to be invented, with all the work necessary to convert back/forth to it, all because the JVM doesn't have user-definable inline-able value types, which would make `Stream<int>`/`Stream<double>` possible and remove the need for `IntStream`/`DoubleStream`/ etc.